# Why does the forceMerge() operation cause rather slow IO operations in Java 7 on RedHat 6.1?

Tags: java, performance, io, lucene

Currently I am experiencing a problem when using Lucene.

Some of my machines spent too much time(10-20 hours for a index size of 15GB) on forceMerge(1). By using some command like top, iostat, jstack.

I found that the avg of cpu, and disk is too low, nearly zero.  And the size of the the index files increased very very slowly. From jstack,

I found that the application is hanging on IO operations, like FileOutputStream or DirectByteArray.

But when I use the command *"echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"* the io may become normal.

Should this issue be related with the JVM, Operating System and hardware?Did anybody met the same problem, or have any idea about Java, Linux and IO.

Some basic info about my system and application.

- Lucece version:4.10.3
- Jdk version:jdk 1.7.0_05
- OS: redhat 6.1
- cpu:IntelX5650
- Memory : 24GB

Comment: What is hard drive configuration?  How many characters are you able to write in a file per second/minute from a single thread?

Comment: How do you know it's Java? as opposed to Lucene, the disk, the operating system, ...

Comment: It's unlikely to make much difference, however you could try a newer version of Java e.g. 7 update 79 or 8 update 60. Update 5 has had a lot of bugs fixed since then.

Comment: Also Redhat 4.4.4 was released in 2006. I don't think Java 7 supported it so you could be getting strange behaviour there. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html suggests that RedHat 5.5. was the minimum for Java 7.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I used to say "when i did some copy operation on the machine the speed may become normal.",  it it not very precise. This probleam happens ramdonly. For the same machine, sometimes it finishs forceMerge in a short time about 1 hour, sometimes it just hangs on IO, and cost nearly 10-20 hours to finish it. If i use "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" to drop the caches, the IO may become normal again. As for the hard driver configuration, it is normal, nearly 100M/s for sequence write, and about 10M/s for ramdom write. I'll use iozone for a more precise result.

Comment: Someone familiar with this issue?